# $_POST Always empty / PHP Storm and Xampp

Tags: php, post

I'm coding on phpstorm and I installed Xampp, I configured Xampp in php storm with the `php.exe` etc.

In order to make it work in the built in server. All was working fine but since yesterday I can't use the `$_POST`.

Here is my test code in one page (the page in `test.php` and if I delete the "action" field in the form it's the same problem):

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_GET);

    ?>
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <input name="test" type="text">
    <button type="submit" name="envoi">Envoyer</button>
    </form>
```

and it shows me

```
array(0) { } array(0) { }
```

If I write something then submit I have the same result.

Comment: try changing to an input submit instead of button <input type="submit" name="envoi" value="Envoyer"> I don't think a button is recognized as part of the <form> tag, but rather a separate object

Comment: i did it same error :/

Comment: sorry, then I am familar with xamp but never heard of php storm, so not sure what that does.  also are you sure the test.php file is the one that you are running the form from within

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xampp PHP server GET works Fine POST isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341521/xampp-php-server-get-works-fine-post-isnt-working)

Answer (score 1):

when the page first load the `POST` array is empty, hence you get

> `array(0) { } array(0) { }`

That is not an error, its correct results as the page first load the array is empty what you need is to check if the form was submitted then return the POST data.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['envoi'])){

    var_dump($_POST);
}


    ?>
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <input name="test" type="text">
    <button type="submit" name="envoi">Envoyer</button>
    </form>
```

on runtime this should give you :

> ```
> array(2) { ["test"]=> string(41) "what ever you have typed in the input box" ["envoi"]=> string(0) "" }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research on Google, back in 2016, PHPStorm own built-in simple web server seemed to have issues handling POST requests. That might still be true today(not entirely sure). I would advise you to use a web server like NGINX, APACHE or any other. It looks like that you already have Apache set up and configured because you installed XAMPP. Try this on your browser: http://localhost/. If the Apache welcome page comes up, you have it setup. Now try to find the DocumentRoot by looking at the Apache configuration settings. Once you find that out, make sure to place your web files there.

Hope it helps